# Angular Material components not displaying correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added a mat-form-field tag in my component but it is not rendering correctly. When not focussed, float-label is not showing. But on selection of matInput input tag , float label is showing. I am attaching screenshots.

**Github URL to repository : https://github.com/Utsav-Sharma33/material**

[image]

[image]

```
<section>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>email</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
</section>
```

```
const mat_modules = [
  MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatIconModule
]

const components = [
  FormFieldComponent,
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...components
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...mat_modules
  ],
  exports: [
    ...components
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

Comment: Can you share the css being applied to your form-field? It seems like you have some css which is overriding material default css.

Comment: @iamentafaz ,

html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }

Comment: I believe you are missing an import for angular material css. Have you imported something like this?- @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css'; Please share a stackblitz if you can

Comment: @PriyankaRao it's already added in my package.json file.

"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],

Comment: I am attaching github url to access the file 
https://github.com/Utsav-Sharma33/material